# Cpanel cron job cant run night or after hours only right?

Tags: cron, cpanel

I searched everywhere but cant get confirmation that a cpanel cron job cant run night or after hours only.

As example

During the day from 6am to 6pm the hour is set to 6-18 but during the opposite and night from 6pm to 6am the hour cant be set as 18-6

Unless there is some solution I guess only way is to run two cron jobs, one from 18-0 and one from 0-6

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was wrong and cpanel inerface allow comma seperated hours so this worked

18,19,20,21,22,23,1,2,3,4,5,6